# OZ960 Intelligent CCFL Inverter Controller - Current Protection Limit Modification

Tags: circuit-protection, over-voltage-protection

I have a SAMSUNG LCD Pc monitor and it shows for one second the logo and then the screen turns to totally black. The problem is on OZ960 Intelligent CCFL Inverter Controller. I bypassed the protection (*I didn't understand or find why the voltage of 1.8V disables the protection on the datasheet but it works*) of the chip as it shown on the below video (at 4.23) and works fine but it has no protection anymore. After search on web as I understanded that the problem is the uneven current that the lamps draw and that triggers the protection of the chip (but I am not sure about this because when I leave only one lamp connected it makes the same thing, so can both lamps have obtain a problem simultaneously?). My question is how can I change he current (or voltage) limit little bit in order not to trigger the protection of the chip and from the other hand the chip will continue to have the protection enable? I beleive that I have to change one of the components that they are connected to pins 9 & 10... I made some changes in the values of the resistors R9 & R8 but with no success.

YouTube Video about the protection disable: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXZ37uFd3vM

Datasheet:
https://dalincom.ru/datasheet/OZ960.pdf

[image]